# UIScrollView will not scroll

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview

I have an iPad app where you can scroll left and right like in the App Store for iPhone. But when I test the app in the simulator, I can't get it to scroll...

Here's my code:

`scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(74, 261, 620, 354); 
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1220, 354)];`

Somebody knows what I have done wrong?

Comment: Some code for the scrollView creation would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

*self.userInteractionEnabled = YES maybe help*